# Pre-compile site in continuous deployment using GIT in Azure App Service

Tags: c#, git, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment, precompile

Is there any way to **pre-compile** whole website during **continuous deployment** in **Azure App Service** (former Azure Websites)?

There are no related settings for publishing in ***Deployment source configuration*** UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using a Kudu [custom deployment script](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38417491924/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart1/).

This is discussed [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1341), which has examples on how you might `call aspnet_compiler.exe` to achieve that (which is the same way you'd do it locally).